# Display dates in a listbox and make it clickable

Tags: jquery, listbox, datepicker

I am creating a page with `datepicker` and getting all the dates that fall between two date ranges.
[image: view]

I want it to display in a `listbox` and make each list of dates clickable. Is that possible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <head>


<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Select a Date Range</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-
 ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
 $(function() {
   $("#from").datepicker();
    $("#to").datepicker();


 $('#getBetween').on('click', function () {
    var start = $("#from").datepicker("getDate"),
    end = $("#to").datepicker("getDate"),
    currentDate = new Date(start),
    between = []
    ;

    while (currentDate <= end) {
    between.push(new Date(currentDate));
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
   }

 $('#results').html(between.join('<br> '));
 
  });


         });
      </script>
  </head>
 <body>

   <input id="from" />
   <input id="to" />
   <button id="getBetween">Get Between Dates</button>

  <ul>
   <li id="results" ></li>
 </ul>

 </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this line:

```
between.push(new Date(currentDate));
```

to this:

```
between.push('<a href="#">' + new Date(currentDate) + '</a>');
```

[**jsbin demo**](http://jsbin.com/eHaHAl/1/edit)

### Updates:

#### HTML:

I have changed your html little bit. i took the id for the `ul` and made it blank(*`without any list items`*)

```
<ul id="results" ></ul>
```

#### jQuery/js:

There are some more changes:

```
between.push('<li>' + new Date(currentDate) + '</li>');
```

1. changed the push, it adds currentDate with some list items.
2. done a click event on the each li and pushed one input type text

The click event to hide other list items and show a text input there:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#results li', function(){
     $(this).siblings('li').hide().end().append('<input type="text" />');
 }).on('click', '#results input', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation(); // <---stops the event to buble up
 });
```

### [See the edited jsbin](http://jsbin.com/eHaHAl/2/edit)

Comment: :Thanks for quick replay and your code works but i need to make the list clickable so that when i click a list it will hide all other list and display a textbox...is it possible???

Comment: yes possible! so you want to show only clicked link and hide others and show a text input field there. right.

Comment: Ya Actualy i doesnt want a link too just want to select each list of dates so that they display a text input(hide others)

Comment: @user2503857 see the updates and the js bin link, is that you wanted.

Comment: Thanks buddy...iam new to this hope your guidence will continue thanks alot

Comment: One more doubt is it possible to add a button After the textfield and in the onclick of button it will generate a textfield on the next raw

Comment: update this line: `$(this).siblings('li').hide().end().append('<input type="text" /><input type="button" value="Go" />');`